# Twilio: sending SMS from US number to French number. Received from French number instead

Tags: sms, twilio

I bought a US phone number with Twilio to send SMS worldwide. It works well with most of the countries, but when I have to send a SMS to a French number, it is being received from a French number (different one each time) instead of from my US number. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely experiencing message filtering on the carriers behalf when [sending an sms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages). You can learn more about why and where this happens [here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-p2p-and-a2p-messaging).